# Cannot find class on runtime even after including the jar files in the classpath

Tags: java, excel, jar, apache-poi, hssf

I am trying to use the *apache poi api*. I have downloaded the jar libraries. This is the code that I have written. The name of the file is *Main.java*.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        File inputFile = new File(".\test.xlsx");
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        Row row;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
            row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
                cell = cellIterator.next();
                System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This what I code that I am running the compile the file.

```
javac -cp "./poi-3.12-20150511.jar;./poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar;./poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar" Main.java
```

I am not getting any errors while I am compiling. But when I am trying to run it I am getting a class not found exception for *HSSFWorkbook*. What am I doing wrong.

PS - All the jar files and my java code are in the same folder.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I running it while typing the command - java Main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -cp "poi-3.12-20150511.jar;poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar;poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar;." Main
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying "Error: Could not find or load main class Main"

Comment: You forgot to add current directory to the classpath. Should be `java -cp ".;..."`

Comment: @Roman Thanks.  You could have edited the post as well.  I knew that he wasn't including the JARs at runtime, just was a bit off with the syntax.